# Sudoku in Clingo

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I am trying to write a sudoku in clingo to learn the syntax a bit more. The part that I am satisfied with correctly represents the column/row constraints:

```
subgrid_size(3).
number(1..S*S) :- subgrid_size(S).
sudoku(X,Y,N) :- initial(X,Y,N).
1{sudoku(X,Y,N): number(N)}1 :- number(X), number(Y). %each coordinate has to have a unique N
1{sudoku(X,Y,N): number(X)}1 :- number(N), number(Y). %a number can only appear once per row
1{sudoku(X,Y,N): number(Y)}1 :- number(X), number(N). %a number can only appear once per col
```

Then I had tried to do something similar to enforce the subgrid constraint:

```
1{sudoku(X,Y,N): subgrid((X-1/S)*S+(Y-1)/S) }1 :- number(N),number(X), number(Y),subgrid_size(S).
```

This did not work, after a long time looking for solutions I found this(which works):

```
subgrid(X,Y,((X-1)/S)*S+(Y-1)/S):- number(X), number(Y), subgrid_size(S).
:- subgrid(X1,Y1,G), subgrid(X2,Y2,G),sudoku(X1,Y1,N), sudoku(X2,Y2,N), X1!=X2, Y1!=Y2.
```

Is there anyway to adapt the `1{...}1:- rule1..ruleN.`  line  for the subgrid constraint so that it works?

Comment: Can you restate your problem? It is not fully clear, at least to me.

Comment: For the other constraints I used rules in the shape `1{...}1 :- rule1.` .  I want to express the constraint for subgrids into the shape of something similar to that and I am not sure why my original idea did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting approach!  The immediate problem is that `subgrid/1` in the choice rule is not defined anywhere.  I get the error message:

> info: atom does not occur in any rule head: subgrid(#Arith0)

Changing the choice rule to use subgrid/3 ...

```
1{sudoku(X,Y,N): subgrid(X, Y, (X-1/S)*S+(Y-1)/S ) }1 :-
    number(N), number(X), number(Y), subgrid_size(S).
```

... and including your `subgrid/3` predicate ... now doesn't return an error, but returns `unsatisfiable`.

Here's what worked for me:

First I changed `subgrid/3` slightly -- adding `+1` to the third argument, so that subgrid labels were 1-9, instead of 0-8, ie now they are `number`s:

```
subgrid(X, Y, (((X-1)/S)*S+(Y-1)/S)+1):-
    number(X),
    number(Y),
    subgrid_size(S).
```

Second, I used this choice rule:

```
1 { sudoku(X,Y,N):
    number(X), number(Y),
    subgrid(X,Y,M)
  } 1 :-
    number(N),
    number(M).
```

ie for every possible `(N, M)` combination, there is one `sudoku(X,Y,N)`, where `(X,Y)` is in subgrid `M`.

Does that work for you?

Comment: I was trying to pack something into more of a oneliner (avoiding subgrid definition altogether), but I think your solution is quite valid regardless and it is more compact. I'll give you the solved :)